# Difference between Sqlalchemy execution time and execution time from EXPLAIN query?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, explain

I am using postgresql with Flask and sqlalchemy.
I found that if I do something like in python,

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
session.query(Table_Class).all()
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print (t2 - t1)
```

I am getting execution time of sqlalchemy query.
But if I go to postgresql and write same sql statement with EXPLAIN ANALYSE then also I can get execution time of sql query. Like,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE select * from table;
```

I found that the difference between these execution times is much. The sqlalchemy execution time is almost 10 times than execution time from EXPLAIN query. For small queries the two times are (75ms and 2 ms) and for long queries with many joins the times are (1.5sec and 200ms). I don't know why this is happening. Why do these times have big difference?

Comment: Are you sure SQLAlchemy generates the same query as you type into postgres console. For example if you have eager-loads, the `session.query(TableClass)` will also perform joins and will generate `select * from a join b join c...`

Comment: Yes SQLAlchemy generates same as I typed in postgres console. I confirmed it by setting `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is probably cause by communication overhead. When you run explain analyse you are measuring the exact time of the query in your postgres database. When you measure the time in the python code you are measuring the time of the query execution plus: the time of connecting to the database, sending the data, receiving/parsing the result, etc. Depending on the amount of data transferred and the physical location of your database you can expect a significant overhead in communication compared to the actual execution time of the query.

Comment: Yea I agree that there will be overhead time but I don't expect it to be in seconds. In my case it is going above 1 second for big queries with long joins.

Comment: @Rohanil How many rows are you retrieving from the database? Is the database on another server? Are you using connection pooling?

Comment: I am retrieving around 1000 rows from db and Database is on same server. For small query with 1000 rows, the times are (75ms and 2ms) and for big queries returning 1000 rows but having many joins, the times are (1.5sec and 200ms).

Comment: If it's only 1000 rows and it sits on the same server it should not have that much overhead indeed. Maybe the way to debug this could be to start with really simple queries returining only 1 element, or even a simple `SELECT 1;` query made in python to see what might be causing the issoe @Rohanil

Comment: " For small query with 1000 rows, the times are (75ms and 2ms) and for big queries returning 1000 rows" small query and big query having the same number of rows?

Comment: @e4c5: I am using small and big words in terms of joins of queries not in terms of number of rows. Small query has no joins in it at all. And big query has many left outer joins in it.

Comment: You simply cannot make such comparisions. That's not even an apples to oranges comparision, it's an apples to breadfruit comparision.